# How to spring bind for multiple level classes like student.userAccount.role?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jstl, one-to-one

I want to know how to perform spring binding for multiple level class mapping. 
I will take an example and explain my problem.

Suppose I have a class hierarchy which says that a **Student**(POJO) has a **UserAccount**(POJO) and the useraccount has a **role**(attribute defined inside **UserAccount** POJO) I want to display the **role** in the JSP using JSTL.

So I have one-to-one mapping for student and useraccount I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate at the backend.

I tried searching on the internet for solutions but I really could not find any useful link.

I want to do form based spring binding.

```
<form:input path = "${student.userAccount.role}" />
```

This is what I am not sure as I did not find working anywhere on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the form `commandName=student` and change the path reference

```
<form:form id="frm" commandName="student" action="/MyController" method="POST">
<form:input path = "userAccount.role" />
```

Assuming they have been added to the model correctly in the controller.